# VS 2008 how to select current file in editor into solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio

It is very time consuming to select file into solution explorer that i am editing. How can i make vs 2008 auto select editor file into solution explorer.

I had it working some point in time back but not sure what needs to change to do that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an option in Visual Studio 2008 called "Track active item" and will automatically select the currently project file being edited.

Activate the option like so

Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Track active item in Soution Explorer